# How do I store URL parameter in user registration field?

Tags: users

I'm trying to store a url variable into a field on the user registration page.

- http://domain.com/user/register?aid=74

Can I use javascript to pull that variable and store it in one of the input fields?

Answer (score -1):

Using hook_form_alter you can set the default value of your field to be this query parameter.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form) {
  $q = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  $form['parameter_field']['default value'] = check_plain($q['aid']);
}
```

Comment: In user regiter tpl file get the query parameter store it in any field you want as a default value.